# Control parallel port using C# Mono in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, parallel-port

As per the title, I want to control a parallel (LPT) port using C# in Ubuntu.

Are there any inbuilt libraries in Mono that will allow me to do this?

Can anyone give any code examples of making this work?

Comment: Nice that whoever downvoted also took the time to explain why. Is the question not useful? Not enough research,what? I spent 4 plus hours to search for the answer and could not find anything. And likewise, why not downvote the answer below, given that it doesn't answer the question and as Dai points out, relates to Windows not Linux as specifically asked for in the question.

And finally, thanks to TheifMaster for removing my edit that 'clarified the question'. Did it not need clarifing? If not, then why not downvote the first answer below who clearly didn't read the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I acknowledge Jesper's contribution, I felt his answer was incomplete and the initial answer gave only references to Windows code as pointed out by Dai. Jesper's follow up comment regarding P/Invoke did lead me down a path to finding the answer.

I have documented my complete solution, including code samples here: http://www.iaincarlin.com/ylsned/controlling-the-parallel-port-using-ubuntu-mono-and-c/ however, in a nutshell:

- There appears to be no native library in C# Mono for accessing the parallel port
- P/invoke is required and I had to create a native C++ application that I could invoke with DLLImport in order to access the LPT1 port.
- The C++ application essentially provides a wrapper round the io library outb function that I can call from C#

My blog post above contains more details regarding the background to what I was doing. I could have used native C++ to do the same thing (in fact it would have been easier to port my existing Dos code over to Linux), but I wanted to experiment with Mono and this was a practical way to do so.

I need to acknowledge the post here: http://www.moythreads.com/wordpress/2008/02/04/pinvoke-how-to-call-c-from-c/ that provided the most helpful in getting this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Guide with basics, and c# code for use of inpout driver and api: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csppleds.aspx

More general collection of links, both technical as well as software related to the parallel port: http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm

I spend quite some time researching this, and never found a native mono library. It's easier for Serial Ports btw.

Comment: The article you linked to only works on Windows as it uses P/Invoke.

Comment: P/Invoke also works on Linux: http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries

Comment: Jasper, thanks for clarifying. I will check out the link in your comment above and see if it helps.